# Can someone help me writing test class,As there is email attachment,Iam really struggling here?

Tags: apex

```
global class FusRefUpd implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
  public static list<string> cusList = new list<string>();
  public static list<string> parList = new list<string>();
  public static list<string> saleList = new list<string>();
  public static list<string> dunList = new list<string>();

  public    List<List<SAP_Fusion_Custom__c>> bundles = new List<List<SAP_Fusion_Custom__c>>();
  public List<SAP_Fusion_Custom__c> bundle = new List<SAP_Fusion_Custom__c>();

  global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) {
    
    Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();
    system.debug('email came');
    string fileAttachments='';
    string subToCompare = 'Update Sap Fusion Number';
    system.debug(+email.subject);
    if(email.subject.equalsIgnoreCase(subToCompare)){
        system.debug('It is under if');
        string fileAttchment = '';
        // Messaging.InboundEmail.TextAttachment[] tAttachments = email.textAttachments;
        // System.debug(' size of tAttachments ' + tAttachments.size() + 'Text Attachement from the email.' + tAttachments);
        Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment[] bAttachments = email.BinaryAttachments;
        System.debug(' Binary Attachement from the email. ' + bAttachments);
        String csvbody = '';
        for(integer i=0; i < bAttachments.size(); i++)
        {
            System.debug(' attacments... ' + bAttachments[i]);
            fileAttachments = String.valueOf(bAttachments[i]);
        }system.debug('No of files:'+bAttachments.size());
        String csvBody1 = '';
        String[] lineByCsvBody = new String[]{};
            List<String> linebycsvdata = new List<String>();
        list<Account> accList2 = new list<account>();
        If(bAttachments != Null && bAttachments.size() > 0){
            For(Messaging.InboundEmail.binaryAttachment ttt : bAttachments)
            {
                
               csvBody1 = ttt.body.tostring();
                //csvBody1 = EncodingUtil.Base64Encode(ttt.body);
                system.debug('Csvbody1'+csvbody1);
                lineByCsvBody = csvBody1.split('\n');
                System.debug('CSV BODY'+ csvBody1 + 'lines' +lineByCsvBody +' size of lineByCsvBody ' + lineByCsvBody.size() + ' This is a Binary Attachment from the email parsed. ' + ttt);
                For(Integer j = 0; j < lineByCsvBody.size(); j++){
                    System.debug(' lineByCsvBody data...... ' + lineByCsvBody[j]); 
                    If(j==0)
                    { 
                        // Here I'm checking and splitting the header values //
                        String headerRow = lineByCsvBody[j];
                        System.debug(' headerRow DATA ...  ' + headerRow);
                        String hvalue = csvBody1;
                        String[] headervalue = headerRow.split(',');
                        System.debug(' size of headervalue ' + headervalue.size());
                        // System.debug(' headervalue1 '+ headervalue[0] + ' headervalue2 ' + headervalue[1]
                        //           + ' headervalue3 ' + headervalue[2] + ' headervalue3 ' + headervalue[4]);
                    }
                    if(j>0){
                        system.debug('Before linebycsvdata add ');
                        linebycsvdata.add(lineByCsvBody[j]);
                        system.debug('Inside j>0'+linebycsvdata);
                    }                                                
                }
                
                
                integer rowcount=0;
                for(String svalue:linebycsvdata) {
                    String[] splitvalue = svalue.split(',');
                    bundle.add(
                        new SAP_Fusion_Custom__c(
                            Name = splitvalue[0],
                            Customer__c = splitvalue[1],
                            Partner__c = splitvalue[2],
                            Sales_org__c = splitvalue[3]
                        )
                    );
                    if(bundle.size() == 10000) {
                        bundles.add(bundle);
                        bundle = new List<SAP_Fusion_Custom__c>();
                    }
                }
                if(bundle.size() > 0) {
                    bundles.add(bundle);
                }
                Database.insert(bundles.remove(0), false);
                if(bundles.size() > 0) {
                    System.enqueueJob(
                        new BulkDataSapFusionCustomInsert(bundles)
                    );
                }
                
               
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    
    return result;
    
    
    
}



}
```

Queuable class*********************

```
public class BulkDataSapFusionCustomInsert implements Queueable {
    List<List<SAP_Fusion_Custom__c>> bundles;
    public BulkDataSapFusionCustomInsert(List<List<SAP_Fusion_Custom__c>> bundles) {
        this.bundles = bundles;
    }
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        Database.insert(bundles.remove(0));
        if(bundles.size() > 0) {
            System.enqueueJob(this); // Do again while more
        }
    }
}
```

**************************Test Class***********************

```
@isTest
public class FusRefUpdTest {

public static SAP_Fusion_Custom__c sapFusion;
public static list<SAP_Fusion_Custom__c> sapList;    
    
public static void testDataSetup(){
        sapFusion = new SAP_Fusion_Custom__c();
        sapFusion.name = 'test';
        sapFusion.Customer__c = '3002499';
        sapFusion.Partner__c = 'AG';
        sapFusion.Sales_org__c = 'Q874';
        insert sapFusion;
}    
    
 public static testMethod void Updatesap(){
     testDataSetup();
     Test.StartTest();
      try{
            Messaging.InboundEmail email=new Messaging.InboundEmail() ;
            Messaging.InboundEnvelope env=new Messaging.InboundEnvelope();
            email.subject = 'Update Sap Fusion Number';
          Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment[] bAttachments = 
     new List<Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment> {
       new Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment(),
       new Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment()
     };

        bAttachments[0].body = Blob.valueOf('attachment0');  // set properties of 1st attachment
        bAttachments[0].filename = 'attach1.bin';
        bAttachments[0].mimeTypeSubType = 'whatever';
        
        email.BinaryAttachments = bAttachments;
          
         
         FusRefUpd obj = new FusRefUpd();
           obj.handleInboundEmail(email, env);
           
          }catch(Exception ex){
            System.debug('ERROR OCCURED:'+ex.getMessage());
        }
     Test.StopTest(); 
        list<SAP_Fusion_Custom__c> sapList = [select id,name,Customer__c,Sales_org__c from SAP_Fusion_Custom__c where id =: sapFusion.id];
        system.assert(sapList[0].name!=null);
      }
    
     
    
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please [edit] your post to show your work so far and ask a specific question. You can learn more about the SFSE format at [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: @DavidReed Updated that post i.e included test class what i have written,after that i am stuck i.e how to proceed further?

Answer (score 2):

One issue you have is that you are not properly mocking the binary attachments

```
Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment[] bAttachments = email.BinaryAttachments;
```

You need to do something like:

```
Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment[] bAttachments = 
     new List<Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment> {
       new Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment(),
       new Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment(),
       ...  // however many you want to mock
     };

bAttachments[0].body = Blob.valueOf('columnHeader1,columnHeader2\nval11,val12\n,...');  // set properties of 1st csv attachment
bAttachments[0].filename = 'attach1.csv';  // whatever name you need
bAttachments[0].mimeTypeSubType = 'text/csv';
// repeat for bAttachments[1], [2], ...

email.BinaryAttachments = bAttachments;  // assoc to mock inbound email
```

Comment: Thanks but still having 68% test coverage

Comment: my answer was simplfied; you need to mock binary attachments that look like csvs. The lines of code not covered will tell you how the mocked inbound email needs to look - also, a testmethod without asserts is near useless